# how to include dependencies for related projects in publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, project, .net-5

I have a solution with two .NET5 projects, ProjectA and ProjectB.

ProjectA is a console application that depends on Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting, and ProjectB is an ASP.Net 5 application that references ProjectA.

When publishing ProjectA (either using `dotnet publish` or via Visual Studio) everything is fine. Both ProjectA.exe and its related depencies are included.
But if I publish ProjectB, I only get ProjectA.exe. I don't get all the required .dll files to run ProjectA.exe.
If I start ProjectA.exe, I get the following error:

```
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (ProjectA.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration', version: '5.0.0'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll'
```

I have tried including Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting directly in ProjectB, but that doesn't work.

I have also tried making a console application ProjectC that references ProjectA, and this works as expected.

There is an example repo here: https://github.com/kalleguld/deps-test

How do I make a publish profile that lets me run both ProjectA.exe and ProjectB.exe?

Comment: Hi, I've downloaded your project from the github link you provided and it can run well in vs. When I visit localhost:5001/api/string, I can get result string `Hello, StringProvider`. Then I try to publish projectA, it's ok, then next publish projectB, it's also ok. I choose to publish to folder. This is what my publish folder looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKz28.png   I'm afraid you need to restart vs or rebuild the code. Or try to clean the vs client cache. What I mean is your code is ok at least.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. The problem comes when I publish ProjectB, then run ProjectA.exe inside the published folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, does what you said `run ProjectA.exe inside the publish folder` means after publish projectB, and you double click projectB.exe, at this time projectA will auto start which then makes you can get `Hello, StringProvider` when visit `localhost:5001/api/string` ? Or something else? In my side, after publishing projectB and double click projectB.exe, I can get that string response when visit that url.

Comment: No I want to double click ProjectA.exe from ProjectB's publish folder.
Like this:
   `cd ProjectB`
`dotnet publish`
`cd bin/Debug/net5.0/publish`
`.\ProjectA.exe`

Comment: I can reproduce your issue but I can't find the reason and don't know how to deal with it. Sorry for it : (

Answer (score 0):

If you want to both projectA and ProjectB can start in the same folder, you can first run `dotnet publish` command from ProjectB root folder to publish the projectB.

Then run the `dotnet publish` command from ProjectA with `-o {projectB/pubilish path}` parameter to publish the projectA to the publish path of Project B.

More details about `dotnet publish` command, please refer to the link below:

[dotnet publish command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish)